# Zuul as OAuth2 AuthServer and ResourceServer: share AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

I'd like to have the Zuul Proxy as SSO `@EnableOAuth2Sso`and as Resource Server `@EnableResourceServer` at the same time.

After some research I found a lot of similar question here on stackoverflow and this lovely [uaa-behind-zuul-sample](https://github.com/kakawait/uaa-behind-zuul-sample) project on github.

1. I removed the user and password property from `application.yml` of the `uaa-service`
2. I added more users for authentication and disabled the parentAuthenticationManager

like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
      .and()
      .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
      // Disables this line below:
      //  auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

3. It works fine in the **browser** with `admin` and `user` credentials. So authorization is fine there.

**But** a call from another client like
`curl --insecure -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n 'acme:acmesecret' | base64)" http://localhost:8765/uaa/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=admin -d password=admin -v`

results in
`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}`

With the log message: 
`o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider   : User 'admin' not found`.
The same happens with `user` and `password`. **And** I works if I leave the user defined in the `application.yml`.

**Question:**
Is it possible to share the authentication manager of the `WebSecurityAdapter` with the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`? So that they are configured the same way?

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {           
  endpoints
  // TODO here: use the authenticationManager from the other class 
    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
}
```

I forked the project mentioned above with a separate branch https://github.com/mavogel/uaa-behind-zuul-sample/tree/integration-resource-server which can be easily setup by running `./build_run.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

1. Exposing the AuthenticationManager from `LoginConfiguration`

   @Override
   @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }
2. Injecting it in the `AuthorizationServerConfiguration`

like this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

3. I also added a protected resource only accessible for the `ROLE_ADMIN` in the `DummyServiceApplication` which gets an `ACCESS_DENIED` for the `user`:

like this

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('openid') and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "secret", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String helloSecret(Principal principal) {
    return principal == null ? "Hello anonymous" : "S3CR3T  - Hello " + principal.getName();
}
```

Props to the PiggyMetrics project who brought me up to the solution